# What is a good GRDB pattern for accessing properties of related objects?

Tags: grdb, grdbcombine

I'm fairly new to GRDB, but I've worked with ORMs and similar object-oriented data layers in the past. I've been using GRDB with SwiftUI, and I've run into a a question I haven't found an answer for in the documentation.

Let's say I have some model objects that look like this:

```
struct Game {
    static let visitorTeamForeignKey = ForeignKey(["visitorTeamId"])
    static let homeTeamForeignKey = ForeignKey(["homeTeamId"])
    static let visitorTeam = hasOne(Team.self, using: visitorTeamForeignKey)
    static let homeTeam = hasOne(Team.self, using: homeTeamForeignKey)

    var visitorTeamId: String
    var visitorTeam: QueryInterfaceRequest<Team> {
        request(for: Game.visitorTeam)
    }
    
    var homeTeamId: String
    var homeTeam: QueryInterfaceRequest<Team> {
        request(for: Game.homeTeam)
    }
}

struct Team: Hashable {
    var id: String
    var logoUrl: String?
    var title: String?
    var divisionTitle: String? // translated from division object
}
```

I would like the Game to have a resolved `description` that includes the names of the teams. In order to do this from the Game itself, I would have to retrieve the teams, and to retrieve the teams I'd need a reference to the database.

What is the recommended pattern to do something like this? Is it to do a JOIN query that includes the teams and then hydrate some other object that includes all fields? Or something else?

Comment: Answers to your question are documented at https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/Documentation/AssociationsBasics.md#joining-and-prefetching-associated-records. It is not recommended that `Game` has a property that depends on its teams, because this means your app _could not handle games independently from their teams_ (undesirable). Instead, build the game description when needed (very probably with including(all:)). See the documented examples - "Fetch all authors along with the titles of their books" looks similar to your needs.

Comment: Thanks @GwendalRoué - you are by far the best open source project maintainer I've ever seen online. Your work is impressive, and GRDB is awesome! Thank you for what you do.

Comment: Thanks :) Tell other maintainers to improve!